# Why is Void a structure?

Tags: c#, .net

I realized that in the Microsoft .NET Framework the `void` return type is a structure. Why?

```
...
public void TestMethod()
{

}
...
```

Comment: I think the op is confusing the [void](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb(v=vs.80).aspx) keyword and the [System.Void](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.void.aspx) structure used in Reflection.

Comment: Indeed, the key point here: a `void` method **doesn't** (in IL terms) return anything. If you wrote IL that tried to read or "pop" the returned value from such a method, then the CLI (and PEVerify) would tell you that you've knackered the stack.

Comment: The Rx designers also went with a struct for [`Unit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.unit(v=vs.103)), for whatever that is worth. Possibly to stay in line with `Void`.

Comment: @ligos: a Unit-returning method really returns something, whereas a void-returning method does not. Having Unit be a structure avoids an useless reference look-up. It's a tiny optimization, but a costless one.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The framework uses [a value type called `System.Void`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.void.aspx) to represent the `void` return type keyword for use with reflection. Although `void` means the lack of a return value, it's still technically a type, and in order for it to be expressed as such in code it has to be either a structure (value type) or a class (reference type).

See [`MethodInfo.ReturnType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.returntype.aspx) for an example.

As to why the framework designers chose to make `System.Void` a structure and not a class is anybody's guess, but it has to be represented by a type in the first place. I'd agree with the comments that it's to avoid the unnecessary overhead typically associated with reference lookups, among other optimizations.

Comment: My "best guess" is that they wanted it to look, to inspecting code, as close as possible as something that returns 0 bytes. A struct without fields is 0 bytes, where-as a class reference is 4 or 8. Although importantly, at the IL level it obviously doesn't return anything, and trying to "pop" those 0 bytes would cause an IL verification fail.

Comment: Additional reading:
http://ahuwanya.net/blog/post/Exploring-SystemVoid-Part-I.aspx
http://ahuwanya.net/blog/post/Exploring-SystemVoid-Part-II.aspx

Comment: Interestingly, I can't seem to find the actual declaration of `struct Void` anywhere in the reference source.  Usually they give a little explanation for these sorts of things in the source comments.

Comment: @BoltClock Just looked at the documentation and the `System.Void` type doesn't appear to have any public properties or any indication that it contains any state - I would surmise someone chose `struct` to avoid reference type overhead during reflection.

Comment: Only a pity you can't use `void` as a type for generics.

Comment: You can find it in the SSCLI20 source.  No explanations.  Its size is 1 btw, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(void)).

Comment: If anyone is interested, `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(void))` is `0` in mono : http://ideone.com/m8qIl , so this may be implementation dependent.